# Last item on Xamarin.Forms ListView on iOS is not reachable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Xamarin.Forms app - on iOS everything is working well but I have an issue with a ListView.

When the collection is updated, the ListView is updated and I can see that new item has been added to the top of the list view but somehow the last item in the view will no longer been shown(!!!) when I go down to the end of the ListView and try to pull the ListView up I can see that the last item is there but it is not shown by default, and it is not reachable I cannot open it.

I tried to rebind the collection again, to do BeginRefresh and EndRefresh but nothing helped. Anyone had this issue? Or how can I force the list view to render again?

Here is an example of the issue, you can see here that the last item is "Test message." (you can see that the frame is not complete - the line in the bottom is not shown). The user thinks that this is the last message he has:
[image]

While, if I pull the ListView I can start seeing the last messages in the ListView:

[image]

But if I get my finger off the screen the list view will return to show the 1st image and the last two messages are gone.

BTW - this issue happen only when I add new message to the ObservableCollection - also if I add two new messages then the last two CellViews won't be shown and so on. This issue happens only on iOS (on Android it works as expected).

Thanks, 
Seif.

Comment: I recently encountered this issue but only only iOS, Android worked fine. As a workaround I calculated the visible height of the ListView based on the device screen height and other views, and set HeightRequest explicitly. It's a rather ugly hack though.

Comment: I fixed it by updating the Xamarin.Forms version to 2.3.2.127.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by updating the Xamarin.Forms version to 2.3.2.127.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a Footer with a blank box view something like:

```
ListView lv = new ListView{
  Footer = new BoxView{
     WidthRequest = 30
  }
}
```

And you can only add this on the iOS project.

Comment: thanks for the comment - this doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a ListView to show mnessages, and when Add new (at the end) I force to scroll down the list... maybe it is usefull for you...

```
var lastMessage = this.listViewMensajes.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().LastOrDefault();
                if (null != lastMessage)
                {
                    if(Animated)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(500);
                        this.listViewMensajes.ScrollTo(lastMessage, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.listViewMensajes.ScrollTo(lastMessage, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
                    }

                }
```

The animated flag is just for show slide effect or not...

Comment: thanks for the message, this solution partially worked, when I did the ScrollTo I saw the last message, but when I scroll up again the last messages are gone again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this issue in Xamarin.Forms version 3.6.0.344457. Is this a regression or are others having issues as well?

I have a custom HtmlLabel inside of a ViewCell - but removing my custom element does not fix the issue.

Comment: Looks like a regression that was introduced in 3.6.0.293080 by this pull request: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/4365. You can find a related bug report here: https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/issues/262

The fix for me was to find a way to be explicit about the ViewCell height, since the new code doesn't estimate the row height properly.